# Android + phonegap + capture.captureAudio

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on the Samsung S Plus phone.

Android version: 2.3.4
Phonegap version: 1.5.0

I am trying to record an audio bit and upload the same to the server.

I am using the Capture API, `capture.captureAudio()`.  When the function
is invoked, on the device I notice that the Voice Recorder application
loads and asks for recording, which I am able to perform.  But, after
the voice is recorded, there is no way for me to select the recorded
audio file and put into my HTML page or atleast I need to path of the
file where its put on the device.  I am unable to select any newly
created recorded audio or the files already available in the library.
Whenever I select any audio file, its plays, but i need that path to
be returned to my application, so that I can do whatever I need to.

The same code works on iOS but not on Android.

The following code is used:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit : 1});
```

`captureSuccess` and `captureError` are some private functions.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: The Full example code under the link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio is used to replicate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've looked at the docs here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html

Can you try and print out debug messages in your success and error callback methods to see what is going on?

Comment: Yes, I did see the Media API.  But, on usage notice that it doesn't have any UI for informing the user that the recording is happening.  Moreover, it expects some time limit as well to be provided.  The user has no option of recording how much ever needed and stop the recording accordingly of their choice.

I did put debug logs / alerts, but neither the success callback or error callback were invoked.

Comment: You said that the Voice Recorder application is started so there is UI informing the user. Also, from the docs page "The capture operation ends when either the user exits the audio recording application, or the maximum number of recordings, specified by the limit parameter in CaptureAudioOptions, has been reached. If no value is provided for the limit parameter, a default value of one (1) is used, and the capture operation will terminate after the user records a single audio clip." So the user can record any length they like and then exit the app. Maybe you can post your JS code?

Comment: I mean to say using Media API there is no UI getting launched.  If I use Capture API, Voice Recorder application (present in the phone) is launched.  I have already posted the code as seen in my original post.

Comment: The link I have mentioned is the Capture API not the media API. It also has sample code to show how the API should be used. I meant post more of your code (including the callback functions) rather than just the single line of code. So your debug statements show that the capture method is getting called?

Comment: I used the same sample code mentioned on the link above.  The error callback was getting called with the error
code: 3, which I guess is CAPTURE_NO_MEDIA_FILES?